# Display the results of a quiz test

Tags: php, mysql

I have to do a quiz test for my company employees and I have a logic problem on displaying the results of the test.

**The database structure:**

- Questions - where i insert from an interface :id , questiontext.
- Answers - where i have : id , question_id , answertext and correct which can have the value = 1 or 0 , 1 if it's a good answer and 0 if it's not. My questions can have multiple correct answers (that's why I'm stuck).
- User_result - where I have id , question_id , answer_id , correct which can be 1 or 0 as in the Answer table , user_test which tells me which test he took based on the level he has more or less questions and the user id which is unique.

**The problem:**

My problem is that I cannot display user result based on the answers he gives if a question has multiple choices, if a question had only 1 correct answer it's simple:

```
$eval = round(($score/40)*100,2);
```

Where $score is a `mysql_num_rows` of all the answers that have correct='1'. 40 is the number of questions that he has to answer.

I also have different types of quiz with 40, 60, 80, and 100 questions - I have them separately on the quiz admin center and i also know which user took which test because I have a record on the database.

What's the best way to display the results?

```
$restest = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                          FROM Tests 
                         WHERE mediu3luni='mediu3luni'", $testaredb);
while($test = mysql_fetch_assoc($restest))
{
    $resvar = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                             FROM Variante 
                            WHERE id_intrebare='{$test['id_intrebare']}' AND 
                                  corect='1'", $testaredb);
    $toatecorecte = mysql_num_rows($resvar);
    $toatevar = mysql_fetch_assoc($resvar);
    echo 'Question'.$toatevar['id_intrebare'].' has'.$toatecorecte.' correct answers<br>';
}
```

The above code will display:

```
 Question id has X correct answers
```

The above code also selects only the questions that are part of the test , this is something that it's configured from the admin panel.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired results (along with a full SQL query if you have one)?  I, for one, don't get what the problem is.

Comment: I've post an edit , thats what i've done since now , by summing all possible question answers i will find out how many correct answers the user must have in order to take 100% score. But i dont know how to sum all of them. After that the formula will be like : $eval = round(($score/$totalchoices)*100,2);

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? Do you want to display the percentage of the correct answers given by all users?

Comment: Yes , but i dont know how to do it when a question has more then 1 answer , if it had only one answer it would be simple user answers = questions but if a question has more than 1 correct answer , percentage of correct answer = user_corect_answers / total_corect_answers *100 ,2. I dont know how to find out the total corect answers from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Your post is confusing in a couple of ways: 1) names of tables of database is not consistent with example code. 2) you ask for the number of correct answers for a user, but your example is for the number of times a question was answered correctly.

Edit: revised taking into acoount comment to this answer.

So, using your "database structure" names:

Number of correct answers by a user:

```
SELECT count(question_id) AS score
FROM   User_result
WHERE id = 'user_id' and user_test = 'a' and correct = 1
```

You can do similar to return the number of correct answers in a quiz

Comment: I might be a bit confusing so i explain agai : I have question A wich have 2 correct answers and question B wich have only 1 correct answer.If the test has only this 2 questions for the user to have 100% he has to have 3 correct answers the 2 from the A question and 1 from the B question. In order to calculate his result i must know the number of all correct answers and the user corect answers. With this 2 things know i can calculate his's score. I dont know how can i get from the database the number of all correct answers for a specific set of questions. I will try what you posted.Thanks

Comment: no, what I posted is not what you wanted. I'll revise it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

**ERM:**

```
+-----------+
| question  |
+-----------+
| id     PK |
| text      |
+-----------+

+-----------------+
| answer          |
+-----------------+
| id           PK |
| question_id  FK |
| text            |
| correct         |
+-----------------+

+--------------+
| user_result  |
+--------------+
| user_id   PK |
| answer_id PK |
+--------------+
```

You only need to know what `answer` a `user` gave, the relation to the `question` already is in the `answer`.

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
    q.id,
    COUNT(a.id) as total_answers,
    SUM(a.correct) as correct_answers
FROM
    question q
INNER JOIN
    answer a ON (q.id = a.question_id)
INNER JOIN
    user_result ur ON (ur.answer_id = a.id)
GROUP BY
    q.id
```

What we basically do here is getting all `user_result`s for each `answer` on each `question`, grouped by the `question`s ID. We then count the `user_result`s (all answers given) and sum up each of their `correct` flags, which results in an equation like this: `0 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 0 ...`, which is the number of correct answers given by all users.

If you want a specific user or a specific question, simply add this condition to the `WHERE` part of the query. This works for multiple correct answers, as well as single ones on as many answers as needed.

**PHP:**

In PHP you could then be doing something like this:

```
<?php
$id = 12;

$query = "... WHERE q.id = $id";

$result = mysqli_query($query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $total = $row['total_answers'];
    $correct = $row['correct_answers'];
    $percentage = round((($correct / $total) * 100), 2);

    echo 'Correct answers given by all users for question ' . $row['id'] . ': ' . $correct . ' (' . $precentage . '%)<br />';
}
```

Comment: Thank you verry much i will try and see what it does in my case.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt helped me , but thank you verry much for trying.

Comment: What problems did you encounter?

Comment: It wasnt returnig anything but i managed to do It . Helped me alot you re ideea with INNER JOIN. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Perhaps the query didn't match your exact database design, that's why I suggested a simpler one and said that you might try something *like* this ;)